# Why doesn't Naruto have/use his Six Paths power?

Tags: naruto

Sasuke still has his Six Paths power, the Rinnegan. I understand that the other Tailed Beasts are no longer in him... **but** in the 4th War, even when Madara pulled out the Nine Tails, Obito gave him the One Tail and the Eight Tails chakra; thus, he was able to use his Six Paths power since he already had chakra of all the other tailed beasts.

Why doesn't Naruto have his Six Paths power?

Comment: The Rinnegan is not a six-path power, It was awakened before Sasuke ever had six-paths abilities. All the six-path chakra (yin/yang chakra) was returned to the Sage of Six Paths after the sealing of Kaguya.

Comment: @Theyna In order to receive the Rinnegan, you have to have the Uchiha and the Senju Chakra and Sasuke did not possess the Senju Chakra. Also when Sasuke was pierced by Madara with his Sword and Naruto was about to die because the 9 Tails was extracted from him.. Hagoromo has appeared and given them the Sage Power and that's when Sasuke got his Rinnegan. (Ep. 421)

Comment: @Theyna Recall, Sasuke got his rinnegan and rinnesharingan when hagoromo gave him six paths power, like Soul said. Naruto got the Senjutsu half, gaining truth seeker orbs and the ability to hover. Though in Boruto the movie, Sasuke still has the rinnesharingan, Naruto seems to not have (or at least use) the six paths senjutsu.

Comment: @Ryan yes, but the rinnegan cab also be attained without six paths power whereas the truth seeker orbs can only be obtained with six paths chakra

Comment: @Theyna Rinnegan can only be obtained by fusing Asura and Indras Chakra, which technically is six paths power.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naruto did not lose his Six Paths senjutsu because he can still manipulate truth seeking balls, and his eyes also exhibit that he is using it in battle (tailed beast eyes crossed with sage eyes with no eye shadow).

Sasuke awakened the Rinnegan because Kabuto used Hashirama's cells to heal him after Madara impaled Sasuke with a sword. Thus, Asura's chakra mixed with Indra's chakra, becoming Hagoromo's chakra, thus allowing Sasuke to awaken the Rinnegan.

Basically, nothing has changed, except that Naruto and Sasuke can't use the Six Paths Sealing jutsu anymore because it can only be used once per lifetime and the two already used the jutsu to seal kaguya

Answer (score 3):

After Sasuke and Naruto sealed away Kaguya, Naruto lost his Sage Of the Six Paths powers (SOSP). This is most likely because Hagoromo gave Naruto and Sasuke powers to defeat Madara or basically Kaguya. That is most likely the reason Naruto lost his SOSP powers.

Sasuke, on the other hand, cannot use the Sage of Six Paths senjutsu, but he can still use Rinnegan. I would imagine that it has gotten weaker since Sasuke in one of the *Boruto* manga had to charge up his Rinnegan powers and he no longer has the SOSP senjutsu.

Comment: Naruto didn't lose Six Paths Senjutsu, his eyes are evident of that. I'm pretty sure those sun and moon marks were simply there for those "limited-time" jutsu, like Six Paths: Planetary Devastation, and the Creation of all Things technique.

Answer (score 2):

Naruto and Sasuke do not have Six Paths power. They lost this after sealing Kaguya.

The *Boruto* designs contradict that of *Naruto: Shippuuden* because Naruto in So6P (*Naruto: Shippuuden*) is seen having the same pattern that Juubidara, Juubito, and Hagoramo had. But, in the *Boruto* series, it's KCM, not So6P. In his fight against Momoshiki, it's KCM because you can see the Kurama Chakra Mode from his tongue.

Sasuke, on the other hand, still has the Rinnegan but doesn't have Six Paths power because every other Rinnegan (Hagoromo Rinnegan) user could use the Six Paths abilities. And, with Six Paths powers, they do not run out of chakra, as we see Sasuke could spam Susanoo more than twice after getting it destroyed. Whereas in the *Boruto* series he got knocked down and couldn't stand up, resulting in him using Amaterasu instead of his Rinnegan genjutsu.

Answer (score 2):

the reason he doesnt use the 6 paths power is not bc he sealed kaguya bc they then used there 6 paths power to stop the infinite sukoyome  its bc when narato and sasuke fight they both lost there arms in the battles they lost the arms with the light and dark marks and hogoromos charka in it and the reason susuke still has his sharirenigan is bc he awakened it bc he had the six paths charka to trigger its awaken and the charka then went into his eye which then let him keep some of his 6 paths chakra.

Answer (score -1):

Naruto has and uses his Six Paths power.

In *Boruto*, when Naruto & Sasuke fights Momoshiki, he uses his Six Paths power against Momoshiki. Naruto has Kyuubi chakra and Sage Mode chakra mixed together, and when he mixes them, there are no pigments. However, when he uses regular Frog Sage Mode (or whatever it's called), there are pigments under his eyes with Sage Mode, and when Naruto came back from the psyche plane with Hagoromo, he received his chakra and received Six Paths Sage Mode.

In *The Last: Naruto the Movie*, he also uses Six Paths power and Ashura's Fist.

---

About Sasuke's Rinnegan, it's because he got Hagoromo's chakra *directly*, not because of Hashirama's cells.

About the whereabouts of his Truthseeker Orbs, they can only be used once, then they are gone.